# Express js using two middlewares for one route

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have my route `router.post('/invite', adminAuth, async (req, res) => {`
And i need additional middleware for this route.
Example - adminAuth opens this route for admin and if admins subscription activated.
But if user admin and subscription is canceled i need still be able to open this route for him.

I try like this `router.post('/invite', [adminAuth, addMiddleware], async (req, res) => {`

But this still not working.

My adminAuth middleware looks like this

````
  const token = req.headers['x-access-token'] || req.headers.authorization;

  if (!token)
    return res
      .status(401)
      .json({ success: false, message: 'Access denied. No token provided.' });

  try {
    req.user = jwt.verify(token, config.get('secretToken'));

    if (
      req.user.userType === USER_TYPES.ADMIN &&
      req.user.isStripeSubscriptionActive
    ) {
      next();
    } else {
      return res.status(401).json({
        success: false,
        message:
          'User is not admin or subscription was canceled! P.S. MIDDLEWARE.',
      });
    }
  } catch (ex) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      success: false,
      message: 'Invalid token P.S. MIDDLEWARE.',
    });
  }
};

 module.exports = {
    adminAuth,  
};```
````

Comment: Did you try this: `router.post('/invite', adminAuth, addMiddleware, async (req, res) => {`

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah, still works first middleware and second not even touched :(

Comment: Do you realize that the second one ONLY gets called if the first one calls `next()`.  If you send a response and don't call `next()`, then the request is done and no more middleware gets called.  So, I'd suggest you add `console.log()` calls to the first one so you can trace exactly where its logic goes and verify that it is calling `next()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 so first one check if user admin and subscription == true, if not first middleware return response and second is not even touched, so i need to writte one middleware for both cases ? if use admin and subscription == true and user admin and subscription == false ?

Comment: If the logic needs both pieces of information to make a decision, then you probably will want to combine them into one middleware.  I don't follow what logic you're trying to implement so I can't make a more specific recommendation.